# I'm trying to create a function that Randomizes three numbers in range (0-100) and prints the largest one

Tags: javascript, math, random

... But when I call the function in the console it returns undefined. I'm a JavaScript newbie so I'm probably making a basic mistake, I'd be greatful if someone could help me out :-).

Here is the code:

```
var randomPrint = function(){

x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

   console.log(x, y, z);

   if(x > y && x > z)
   {
     console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + x);
   }
   else if(y > z && y > x)
   { 
     console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + y);
   }
   else if(z > y && z > x)
   {   
    console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + z);
   }
};
randomPrint();
```

Comment: I would like to note that if the two largest numbers are equal you will not print anything. As for the question: where is the undefined being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from deceze is a better solution, but I see your working as well. An example output in the console is:

```
35 50 47
The greatest number is 50
undefined
```

the undefined part is because the function is not returning anything. You could write it as

```
var randomPrint = function(){

    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

   console.log(x, y, z);

   if(x > y && x > z) {
        var biggest = x;
        console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + x);
   } else if(y > z && y > x) { 
       console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + y);
       var biggest = y;
   } else if(z > y && z > x) {   
       console.log("The greatest number is" + " " + z);
       var biggest = z;
   }
   return biggest;
};

randomPrint();
```

Comment: Problem is this fails if two numbers are equal.

Comment: Yes I noticed it as well, didn't mention it though because it's not part of the question. Let him hit his head on that problem as well, he's learning js :)

Answer (score 1):

The sane way:

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}

console.log('Largest number is ' + Math.max.apply(null, nums));
```

Or:

```
nums = nums.sort();
console.log('Largest number is ' + nums[nums.length - 1]);
```

And yes, the function will *return* `undefined` since you're not *returning* anything from the function. Likely none of your conditions match, so you're not seeing any other output either.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this, inbuilt method to get max

```
Math.max(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can throw away the other two numbers:

```
for (var i = 0, max = -Infinity; i < 3; ++i) {
    max = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), max);
}

alert(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var randomPrint = function(){

    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

       console.log(x, y, z);
       console.log("this is max " +Math.max(x,y,z);)
}();
```

Your logic is not wrong either . Its fine that undefined might be coming somewhere else .

> 88 36 15 localhost/:16
>   The greatest number is 88

This is output of your code i got.